# filter angularjs don't working

Tags: angularjs, filter

In my web the people can create events and sign up. In the event list there are two buttons ( sign up/ sign off ).
button ( sign up ): when you press this button you will add you in the event like assistant.
button (sign off). when you press this button you will remove of event.
this working well, but the problem is in the filter:

```
{{ event.attendees }} // working well because is updated when press the button
{{ ([event.attendees] | filter:currentUser.id).length }} // not working always is 0 

<button id="signup" ng-click="sign(event.attendees, currentUser.id)" ng-show="([event.attendees] | filter:currentUser.id).length == 0">
<button id="signdown" ng-click="sign(event.attendees, currentUser.id)" ng-show="([event.attendees] | filter:currentUser.id).length == 0"> 


controller(){

$scope.signup = function(attendees, currentUser_id) {
    attendees.push(currentUser_id);
}
```

i want that when you press the button signup making fadeout in button signup and fadein in button signdown but the filter not working because don't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrapping event.attendees in square brackets. That means what you're actually doing is filtering an array with a single element, your array of attendees. This will never find the string you're searching for. Try this instead:

```
{{ (event.attendees | filter:currentUser.id).length }}
```

Now, I have had bad experiences with infinite digest loops using the same filter in multiple places on a page, and this isn't really the way filters are supposed to be used anyway. So, I recommend you consider adding an isSignedUp function to your controller. You can implement this easily using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere):

```
$scope.isSignedUp = function(attendees, id) {
    return _.findWhere(attendees, {id: id}) !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Would you mind marking my answer as accepted so that others can see it's resolved?